# How can i change the image in a android gallery at certain times

Tags: java, android, handler, infinite-loop, image-gallery

My goal here is to change the image in my gallery at certain times ,
lets say 5 seconds change , another 5 seconds another change .

Some sort of infinite loop using a handler to change the
img but i think this approach would consume a lot of battery .

what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see nothing wrong in your approach.

Activity classes always consume a lot of the battery.

Just stop the timer in onPause().